# Dictionary Direct access vs TryGetValue

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary which maps strings to objects like this:
`Dictionary<string, object> myDic;`

I know prior what the type of the object is based on the string, but my question is whether I should use TryGetValue, or direct lookups with try, catch statements.

Example:

```
//TryGetValueMethod
object myObject = null;
myDic.TryGetValue("test", out myObject);

MyCustomType t1 = (MyCustomType) myObject;

//Direct lookup method
try
{
     MyCustomType t2 = (MyCustomType) myDic["test"];
     //Do something here...
} catch {}
```

What method do you think is preferred? The second one is more clean coding because there are no extra castings, but i think it is less efficient than the first, because it is exception-free.

Comment: What is the expected behavior is the object isn't found in the dictionary?

Comment: Why would you use `Dictionary<string, object>` instead of `Dictionary<string, MyCustomType>` if you know that's what it's meant to hold?

Comment: No i can have any object type, but having a specified string i know the value type. E.g test maps to a MyCustomType object, test1, maps to a MyCustomType2 object.

Comment: That particular `catch { }`. Never do that. Don't even think it.

Comment: Yead the catch {} is just for example-sake.

Comment: @Dimis92 you should use your first approach. Its even better than the accepted answer since the latter is two lookups, while yours is one..

Comment: @nawfal isn't throwing an exception expansive?

Comment: @Dimis92 yes relatively if you meant "expensive", and furthermore a bad habit to handle something that's known beforehand (exception catching is meant for exceptional cases). Thats why I said your first approach is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you should use `try`/`catch` to form a logical path like that. `Exception`s are supposed to be exceptional cases, where something has "gone wrong".

Personally, I prefer `ContainsKey`:

```
if (myDic.ContainsKey("test")) {
   MyCustomType value = myDic["test"];
   // do something with the value
}
```

If you think that not finding the key means that something has "gone wrong", then I would omit the test, and let an exception be thrown if the key is not found.

EDIT: these days I try to use `TryGetValue` instead. It's slightly more clumsy, but once you get used to it, it's not so bad.

```
MyCustomType value;
if (myDic.TryGetValue("test", out value)) {
   // do something with value
}
```

EDIT2: Now with `out var` I definitely use `TryGetValue` a lot more. Similarly you can write a `CantGetValue` method (same thing with opposite boolean result), since most of the time you want to do something extra when there *isn't* a value, not when there is.

```
if (dict.TryGetValue("test", out var value)) {
   // do something with value
}

// or

if (cache.CantGetValue("test", out var cachedValue)) {
   // cache value
}
// make use of value
```

Comment: Yeah i think the best should be to go to with ContainsKey. It is more clean coding than TryGetValue when you want to do castings, as in this case.

Comment: Why look up twice what you can look up once. If you had a old-fashioned telephone directory and wanted someone's phone number would you look it up once and then if you had found that it was in there, close the directory and then look it up again?

Answer (score 5):

MSDN says *"Using this method [TryGetValue] is more efficient than catching the KeyNotFoundException thrown by the Item property."*

It also explains that `TryGetValue` *"combines the functionality of the `ContainsKey` method and the Item property"*..

You should also catch only that specific exception not all exceptions.

**Update:** As of C# 7 you can now write:

```
if (myDic.TryGetValue("test", out MyCustomType value)) {
   // do something with value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can safely predict that the key should always exist, then wrap it in the Try ... Catch.  This way an exception will be thrown only when something's gone wrong.

The `TryGetValue` is a better option - `Dictionary.ContainsKey(key)` is just as good - ultimately it does the same thing as `TryGetValue` behind the scenes.

Comment: "loop the keys until it finds (or doesn't) the key". I don't think this is correct. A Dictionary is a hash table. `ContainsKey`, `TryGetValue`, and indexing should all be basically O(1) operations, not O(n).

Comment: It still stands that they both do the same thing, but yes you're right - it's a hash table.  I'll amend my answer.