# Get a value from dictionnary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm stuck on something probably easy but I can't find how to solve that
So It's the first time I used the dictionnary and in my code I have declared my variable:

```
Private Dictionary<string, bool> g_objDictionnary =new Dictionary<string, bool>();
```

and In my code I'd like to do something like:

**If my g_objDictionnary bool for this key is true so do that**.
Which function have to use to do that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: if(g_objDictionnary[key]) { //doStuff }

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-dictionary) for an introduction to the C# `Dictionary` type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906675/dictionary-direct-access-vs-trygetvalue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's already a bool, you can just this:

```
if (g_objDictionnary["some_key"]) {
    // Go!
}
```

This assumes the key already exists in your dictionary.

Comment: Thank you,
Yes before I checked if my key is in my dictionnary

Answer (score 4):

For an one liner to check if the key exists and get its value if so, you can do something like this:

```
if (g_objDictionnary.TryGetValue("some_key", out var value) && value) {
   // Do something
}
```

**Edit**
As HimBromBeere stated in the comments this syntax will only work for C#7 and higher. If you are using a version of C# below 7 you have to declare `value` beforehand:

```
bool value;
if (g_objDictionnary.TryGetValue("some_key", out value) && value) {
   // Do something
}
```

Comment: works only from C#7 onwards. Before you´d have to declare `value` outside the statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(g_objDictionnary.ContainsKey(yourKey))
 if(g_objDictionnary[yourKey] == true)
 {
 }
```